# Unable to insert channel banner to YouTube through YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

API link - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelBanners/insert

I referred the above API link to create banner for my YouTube channel. As specified in the document, I uploaded the binary image data to YouTube using channelBanners.insert endpoint

**Request**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/channelBanners/insert
```

**Response**

```
{
    "kind":"youtube#channelBannerResource",
    "etag":"XNLrbVGUJFqOLlEad5EXo5pry6Y",
    "url":"https://yt3.ggpht.com/HV5PNcUGNnPTFRvkOt3fcKk9joOm1hxhN5OrgP8ei8cZKNnbS894i3gtT5vP204JRBpO4nUbpw"
}
```

Then I tried to update the channel banner using the image URL (https://yt3.ggpht.com/HV5PNcUGNnPTFRvkOt3fcKk9joOm1hxhN5OrgP8ei8cZKNnbS894i3gtT5vP204JRBpO4nUbpw) I got in the above API call.

**Request**

```
PUT https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings
```

**Request body**

```
{
  "id": "UCnO4od0EVfOtKpJvATez3dA",
  "brandingSettings": {
    "image": {
      "bannerExternalUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/HV5PNcUGNnPTFRvkOt3fcKk9joOm1hxhN5OrgP8ei8cZKNnbS894i3gtT5vP204JRBpO4nUbpw"
    }
  }
}
```

**Error Response**

```
{
 "error": {
 "code": 400,
 "message": "Required",
 "errors": [
 {
 "message": "Required",
 "domain": "global",
 "reason": "required"
 }
 ]
 }
}
```

Getting 400 error response when I try to update the channel banner by setting brandingSettings.image.bannerExternalUrl property in the request body. Kindly provide a solution to this issue.

Thanks,
Rajalakshmi

Comment: It seems that [the image you uploaded](https://yt3.ggpht.com/HV5PNcUGNnPTFRvkOt3fcKk9joOm1hxhN5OrgP8ei8cZKNnbS894i3gtT5vP204JRBpO4nUbpw) (512 x 288 pixels) doesn't fit [YouTube channel banner requirements](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelBanners/insert): "The image must have a 16:9 aspect ratio and be at least 2048x1152 pixels. We recommend uploading a 2560px by 1440px image."

Comment: I uploaded image with 4096 × 2304 dimensions in channelBanners.insert API call. It returns this image URL - https://yt3.ggpht.com/HV5PNcUGNnPTFRvkOt3fcKk9joOm1hxhN5OrgP8ei8cZKNnbS894i3gtT5vP204JRBpO4nUbpw.

I followed the YouTube channel banner requirements you specified.

channelBanners.insert API call itself is not worked when we gave the wrong aspect ratio. I think the issue is not with the YouTube insert channel API constraints.